# PHP Mail using HTML with PHP if statement embedded

Tags: php, html, email

I currently have PHP sending an HTML email that lists every item from a form even if the quantity is 0. Now I want to change it to only list items that are being ordered (Qty>0). After looking all over the internet to to and find a way to embed a PHP if statement inside an HTML email, this is what I have come up with and it's still not working...

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$AV000100 = $_POST['AV000100'];
$AV000101 = $_POST['AV000101'];
$AV000102 = $_POST['AV000102'];

$comments = $_POST['comments'];
?>

<?php
$to = "me@company.com";
$subject = "Marketing Material Order from $name";
$message = "
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>
        Name: $name<br>
        Email: $email<br>
        Date Needed: $date
    </p>

    <?php if ($AV000100 != 0) {
        $AV000100 - Brochures;
        }
    ?>

    <?php if ($AV000101 != 0) {
        $AV000101 - Folders;
        }
    ?>

    <?php if ($AV000102 != 0) {
        $AV000102 - Pens;
        }
    ?>

<p>Comments: $comments</p>

</body>
</html>
";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
$headers = "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

How do I change the embedded PHP if statement to show this as the email body...

Name: John Doe
Email: jon@mail.com
Date Needed: Today
2 - Brochures
2 - Pens
Comments: Thank you

Instead of...

Name: John Doe
Email: jon@mail.com
Date Needed: Today
2 - Brochures
*0 - Folders*
2 - Pens
Comments: Thank you

FYI...the way I have the PHP if statement written above, none of the items show up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you want - but if you want to use the result of evaluating the PHP code as the message body then you need to use output buffering (or a lot of inline ifs - output buffering is cleaner).

For example, if you put all your code the generate the message body in a file body.php then you could use:

```
ob_start();
include('body.php');
$message = ob_get_Clean();
```

You don't need to have the body code in a seperate file - just include it instead of the include statrement betwen the `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$message = "
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>
        Name: $name<br>
        Email:$email<br>
        Date Needed:$date
    </p>
 ...
 ...";
```

Each time you break the string and then concatenate the string with the `php` results using `.` operator.

Comment: You cannot `echo` inside a string like that.

Comment: Soory @Rolice ..Thanks for pointing out that..i've edited my answer..Can you please remove that downvote...

Comment: Yes, @Lal. It is now accurate.

Comment: If you are using double quotes then you don't need to come out of the quoting to include simple variables.  `$message="something".$else;` is the same as `$message="something$else";`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want to do with what you have.

```
$message = "
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>
        Name: $name<br>
        Email: $email<br>
        Date Needed: $date
    </p>

    " . ($AV000100 != 0 ? $AV000100 . " - Brochures" : "") . "

    " . ($AV000101 != 0 ? $AV000101 . " - Folders" : "") . "

    " . ($AV000102 != 0 ? $AV000102 . " - Pens" : "") . "

    <p>Comments: $comments</p>
</body>
</html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the message line by line if you want using the concatenating assignment operator (`.=`), and put the if statements where you need them. Like so:

```
$message = "<html>";
$message .= "<head></head>";
$message .= "<body>";
$message .= "<p>";
$message .= "Name: $name<br>";
$message .= "Email: $email<br>";
$message .= "Date Needed: $date";
$message .= "</p>";
if ($AV000100 != 0) {
$message .= "$AV000100 - Brochures";
}
if ($AV000101 != 0) {
$message .= "$AV000101 - Folders";
}
if ($AV000102 != 0) {
$message .= "$AV000102 - Pens";
}

$message .= "<p>Comments: $comments</p>";
$message .= "</body>";
$message .= "</html>";
```

You can just send `$message` as usual.

**Here is the full code:**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$AV000100 = $_POST['AV000100'];
$AV000101 = $_POST['AV000101'];
$AV000102 = $_POST['AV000102'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$to = "me@company.com";
$subject = "Marketing Material Order from $name";
    $message = "<html>";
    $message .= "<head></head>";
    $message .= "<body>";
    $message .= "<p>";
    $message .= "Name: $name<br>";
    $message .= "Email: $email<br>";
    $message .= "Date Needed: $date";
    $message .= "</p>";
    if ($AV000100 != 0) {
    $message .= "$AV000100 - Brochures";
    }
    if ($AV000101 != 0) {
    $message .= "$AV000101 - Folders";
    }
    if ($AV000102 != 0) {
    $message .= "$AV000102 - Pens";
    }

    $message .= "<p>Comments: $comments</p>";
    $message .= "</body>";
    $message .= "</html>";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
$headers = "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```